# How to make intersection between two class

Tags: ios, class, delegates, uibutton

I created two classes. In each class there are UIButton and the related event. We can click on this button and the condition will change. If we click on the button in the same class and the second class status button should change. How to realize it there is an assumption to make it through the delegate, but I don't quite understand how.[image]

The result should be something like the image if one of the classes button changes its status as at 1 in the other class this state changed to zero

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem as follows.

I create an Objective-C protocol which contain one required method

```
@protocol MyProtocolForState <NSObject>

- (void)changeStateButton;
```

Next I create class A - this class contain button which will be paired with another class (Class B)

```
#import "MyProtocolForState.h"

@interface A : UIViewController <MyProtocolForState>{
    id<MyProtocolForState.h> delegate;
}
@property (nonatomic, assign)id<MyProtocolForState.h> delegate;
- (IBAction)touchButton:(id)sender;
```

In implementation file I added delegate method and reaction method

```
- (IBAction)touchButton:(id)sender {
    [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    [delegate changeMethod];
}

- (void)changeMethod{
    [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
}
```

Next I create class B - this class contain button which will be paired with another class (Class A)

```
#import "MyProtocolForState.h"

@interface B : UIViewController <MyProtocolForState>{
    id<MyProtocolForState.h> delegate;
}
@property (nonatomic, assign)id<MyProtocolForState.h> delegate;
- (IBAction)touchButton:(id)sender;
```

In implementation file I added delegate method and reaction method

```
- (IBAction)touchButton:(id)sender {
    [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    [delegate changeMethod];
}

- (void)changeMethod{
    [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
}
```

Next i create instance class A and class B and bind them

```
    A * a = [[A alloc] init];
    [a.view setFrame:CGRectMake(50, 50, 100, 100)];
    B * b = [[B alloc] init];
    [b.view setFrame:CGRectMake(200, 50, 100, 100)];
    a.delegate = b;
    b.delegate = a;
    [self.window addSubview:a.view];
    [self.window addSubview:b.view];
```

When I tap on the button in one class in other class we call delegate method and change state for view.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly you would declare a delegate in each class, say in classA :

```
@class ClassB;

interface classA: UIbutton {
    ClassB* delegate;
    ...
}
@property (nonatomic, assign) ClassB* delegate;
- (void) notifystatuschange:(int) status;
```

The @class clause is here to avoid having to import ClassB.h in the interface file. You do import ClassB.h in the implementation file.
You declare the property with assign and not retain as you just want to keep a pointer to the delegate, so you would not alloc or dealloc it.
You need a method to receive the status change notification.

Once you've got this in the callback of the button for classA you would call the notify method on the delegate :

```
-(void) classAcallbak:(ClassA*) sender {
    [sender.delegate notifystatuschange:1];
    ...
}
```

Of course you'll need more ivars to handle the status.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for response! Suppose I have a few classes. For example I have 10 classes. This class inherited from UIButton class (or other class). When I tap on one of these button, this button must change color from black to red. For this group button only one button can be selected color red. It's like that for radio button group. When one button selected other button deselect automatically. Each of this button represented different classes (Class1, Class2, ... Class10).